# When copying an object, is it possible to keep the identity the same?

Tags: python

In the `__init__` function of a class I initialize some variables in order to make them available throughout my class and other classes.
These variables are given a value at a later stage in a function of a different class. But whenever they are set their identity changes. Since I have been passing around the references to these variables I don't want their identity to change.

I have already tried `copy.copy()` and `copy.deepcopy()`, but this also changes the identity of the variables.

The code below describes the situation in a simple way:

```py
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'test_object'
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_object = MyObject()

def create_object():
    new_object = MyObject()
    new_object.set_name('new_object')
    print(f'Address of new object in function: {id(new_object)}')
    return new_object

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_class = MyClass()

    print(f'Identity when variable has only be initialized: {id(my_class.my_object)}')

    my_class.my_object = create_object()

    print(f'Identity after the create has been called: {id(my_class.my_object)}')
```

The code above produces the following output:

```
Identity when variable has only be initialized: 87379952
Address of new object in function: 87425104
Identity after the create has been called: 87425104
```

What I would like to have is that the identity of `my_class.my_object` stays the same and does not change to the identity of the object created in the function. Would someone know how to achieve this?

Comment: The whole *point* of object identity is to distinguish two objects that are otherwise *equivalent*. You cannot copy identities, because then separate objects would not have unique identities.

Comment: You are misusing identities if you require that `copy` preserve the identity.

Comment: It looks like you want `MyObject` to be a singleton.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)

Comment: _why_ are you attempting to do this? this smells of the XY problem.

Comment: Presumably you are using CPython, in which case [the identity returns the memory address](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) at which the object is stored. If you aim to keep those addresses the _same_, you should not make a new object: create it once, and return a reference on subsequent invocations. This is known as a Singleton, as others have remarked above.

Comment: In CPython, an object's identity **is** its memory address.

Comment: @mkrieger1  There could be multiple instances of the class, so it shouldn't be a singleton.

Comment: @Rishav I want to do this, because before giving the right values to the class 'my_object' I need to have it's reference.

Comment: Considering your comments, it would be better to: pass the object to the function create_object(), and modify the object accordingly instead of creating a complete different object?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new instance of `MyObject` when initializing an instance of `MyClass`, you can explicitly pass a reference to an existing `MyObject` instance:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'test_object'
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_object):
        self.my_object = my_object

def create_object():
    new_object = MyObject()
    new_object.set_name('new_object')
    print('Address of new object in function:', id(new_object))
    return new_object

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_object = create_object()

    print('Identity after the create has been called:', id(my_object))

    my_class = MyClass(my_object)

    print('Identity when my_class has been initialized:', id(my_class.my_object))
```

Output:

```
Address of new object in function: 140518937186936
Identity after the create has been called: 140518937186936
Identity when my_class has been initialized: 140518937186936
```